# ggplot for one dependent variable and multiple indipendent

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Is it possible to create multiple `ggplots` using `facet_wrap` when having `y` varaible always the same and just changing `x` variable:

Lets say we have:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

colnames(mtcars)

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(hp, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")


mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(hp, cyl)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(hp, disp)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(hp, drat)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")

.
.
.
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(hp, carb)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

I know plots above can be create manually and then using grid arrange combined, however is there more efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little data augmentation, we can. We first create an "id" using `row_number`, and then use the [`gather`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html) function to go from a wide data set into a tall data set. We deselect the `id` and `hp` columns.

```
mtcars %>%
    mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
    gather(variable, value, -id, -hp) %>%
    ggplot(aes(hp, value))+
    geom_point()+
    geom_smooth(method = "lm")+
    facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]